# Using "not in list" syntax in pandas select

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do something like

```
exclude_values = range(low, high)  # for the sake of example
df = df[df['blah'] not in exclude_values]
```

which just raises the "truth value of a Series is ambiguous" exception. The problem is, I can't see how to change this syntax so as not to use `not in`. What (presumably very obvious) thing am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isin`

```
df[~df['blah'].isin(exclude_values)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use idiomatic pandas methods and bitwise logic:

```
df = df[~round(df.blah).isin(exclude_values)]
```